# React isValidElement comes out as false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is a simple example:

```
const Foo = () => {
    return (
    <div>foo</div>
  );
}

class Bar extends React.Component {
    render() {
    return (
        <div>bar</div>
    )
  }
}

console.log(React.isValidElement(Foo));
console.log(React.isValidElement(Bar));
```

Both of these return false. Why is that?

Comment: Component != Element . An element is basically the result of "instantiating" (also not really, not sure what the right term is) a component. Try `console.log(React.isValidElement(<Foo />));`. Basically, you get an element when you call `React.createElement(Foo)`, which is what `<Foo />` is doing under the hood.

Comment: @FelixKling Ah makes sense. Thanks! I do have another question if the answer is simple, otherwise I'll create a separate question. How do I clone `Foo` or `Bar` and pass additional props to? `React.cloneElement` returns error

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. You can pass as many props to a component as you want. But the component will probably only access the ones it knows about. So when you say you want to pass additional props I assume you want to access them somewhere somehow as well. But that basically means to change the implementation of the function/component, so I don't know what "cloning" a component would do exactly. Maybe you can provide a better example for your use case?

Comment: @FelixKling, okay I'll create a separate question. If you post your comment as answer, I can mark it as the solution!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Component != Element`

`Foo` and `Bar` are *components*. An *element* is basically the result of "instantiating" (also not really, not sure what the right term is) a component. It's the combination of a constructor/function/string (for HTML components), props and children.

You get an element when you call `React.createElement(Foo)`, which is what `<Foo />` is doing under the hood.

```js
const Foo = () => {
    return (
    <div>foo</div>
  );
}
console.log(React.isValidElement(<Foo />));
console.log(<Foo bar={42} />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To check for a function component:

```
typeof Foo === 'function'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Foo = () => <div>foo</div>;

class Bar extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return (
          <div>bar</div>
       )
    }
}

console.log(React.isValidElement(<Foo />));
console.log(React.isValidElement(<Bar />));
```