# React.js check if component exists

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of components, and in real-time I want to whether components exists or not.

For example I have a list of shapes ( they are components ): `Circle`, `Square` and more..

And I want that the user could check if component exists or not, so I thought maybe doing `React.isElementValid(userInput)`:

For example:

```js
if(React.isValidElement('Shape')) {
  console.log("True!");
}
```

but it seems like `Element != Component` According to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46433070/11356272

How can I do that?

Comment: "but it seems like Element != Component", why? Please show some producible example. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash editted my question.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the **string** `'Shape'` is a React Element, which is not.

```
React.isValidElement(Shape); // false, it's a function
React.isValidElement(<Shape />); // true
React.isValidElement('Shape'); // false, it's a string
```

If you want to check if the given value is a **Component** you should consider all possible values that are valid components like `null`, `undefined`, `true`, any `string` type etc.

- See [`render()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) and [JSX-in-Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored)

Also note, a ReactElement is an element [created with `createElement` or `createFactory`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#creating-react-elements).

Comment: So how can I dynamically check if Component exists? from user's input

Comment: You didn't describe what user's input is... are you expecting to write `Shape` and resolve if its a component rendered on the page?

Comment: So you can make an array of all rendered components and filter accordingly.